# Show ViewController after LaunchScreen loaded

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm trying to create a walkthrough(intro) for my app. I am using BWWalkthrough to do it. If want to open this view controller after clicked a button, it works(as you can see in below codes). But I don't want to do this. I want to open this view controller after launch screen loaded.

When I clicked "is initial View Controller" for the master page and added below code in viewDidLoad method, I can see only master page but I can't see view controllers(page_one, page_two ...) attached to master page. Probably I must write some codes in AppDelegate but I don't know how is it

How can I solve this problem?

```
@IBAction func testButton(_ sender: Any) {

    let goStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let walkthrough = goStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "master") as! BWWalkthroughViewController
    let page_one = goStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page1") as UIViewController
    let page_two = goStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page2")as UIViewController
    let page_three = goStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page3")as UIViewController

    **// Attach the pages to the master**
    walkthrough.delegate = self
    walkthrough.add(viewController:page_one)
    walkthrough.add(viewController:page_two)
    walkthrough.add(viewController:page_three)

    self.present(walkthrough, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: i have implemented this before.. but its in obj-c.. still wanna see it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, go to your Main storyboard and create a new view controller. You should also create a view controller class. This is going to be your Home screen storyboard and you're going to set it as your Initial View Controller.

In the class that you previously created, you can put this:

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    override viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let goStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let walkthrough = goStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "master") as! BWWalkthroughViewController
        let page_one = goStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page1") as UIViewController
        let page_two = goStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page2")as UIViewController
        let page_three = goStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page3")as UIViewController

        // Attach the pages to the master
        walkthrough.delegate = self
        walkthrough.add(viewController:page_one)
        walkthrough.add(viewController:page_two)
        walkthrough.add(viewController:page_three)

        self.present(walkthrough, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: A view controller that is the initial view controller cannot present another view controller in its `viewDidLoad` method.